# Proving $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ is countable without theorem of arithmetic.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to show that there exists a bijective function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ without using prime factorization. I have pieces here and there, but unable to put togther a complete proof. It would be great someone could help me out.

This is what I roughly got. I choose a sequence of postive integer $a_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and I know they will be "captured once" by the interval $I_n=(a_{n-1},a_n]$ for all $n\geq 2$. I will let $I_1=\{1\}$. Then once show that there is indeed a bijective function between the set of intervals and the set of number defined by the sequence. I will invoke the property that any infintie subset of a countable set is countable to complete the proof.

Comment: Look up the Cantor pairing function.  It occurs here often.

Comment: Use the first diagonal theorem of Cantor. He uses that to show that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, but you can use it also to show that $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ is countable.